How to make OpenAI Assistant API to retrieve a word document?
I'm trying to make my chatgpt through the api to answer a question and generate a word document with the answer's content, but it says it can't do it. I have also tried telling it to generate an empty word document but it doesn't work either. When I ask it to generate a word document I get the response: I'm sorry, that's not possible. How else can I assist you?
Here's my code:
messages = [
    {
        'role': 'user',
        'content': [
            {'type': 'text', 'text': 'Generate an empty word document.'},
            {"type": "text", "text": "json"}
        ]
    }
]

assistant = client.beta.assistants.retrieve(assistant_id)

thread = client.beta.threads.create(
    messages=messages
)

run = client.beta.threads.runs.create(
    thread_id=thread.id,
    assistant_id=assistant.id
)

After a while I run this code to access the new messages:
msgs = client.beta.threads.messages.list(
    thread_id=thread.id
)

data = msgs.model_dump_json()
json_object = json.loads(data)

But it tells me it cannot generate the file, even when I tell it to put some contents on it.
